UHF tracker / beacon device help
I am in the process of making my own miniature UHF radio transmitter and I ran across this instructable project.
https://www.instructables.com/Tiny-UHF-Tracker-Transmitter/
My question is how the two comparators generate a 915 MHz signal. If the first comparator generates a square wave at ~0.5 Hz and the second comparator converts that to 800-900 Hz, how does the saw filter convert this energy to 915 MHz? Is this possible from the L3 inductor creating an LC tank with the capacitors attached to the transistor?

Don't think of it as "conversion". Think of it as control.  Work backwards from the right.
Q1 and X1 form a 915 MHz oscillator.  The signal arriving through R3 is able to turn that oscillator on or off.  The comparator driving R3 oscillates at 800 Hz, so now what's coming out of the antenna is a 915 MHz signal that is keyed on and off 800 times a second.
Moving to the left one more stage, we have the first comparator that oscillates at .5 Hz. The output is actually being used to power the 800 Hz generator, so it is turning the 800 Hz signal on and off every 2 seconds.  So the final result is a 915 MHz signal, keyed on and off at 800Hz, with the entire signal itself being turned on and off every two seconds.

Thank you for this explanation, it helps a lot. Is there a reason that the 800 Hz comparator is added to the circuit - does it improve the signal strength of the beacon? What disadvantage would there be to just turn on the oscillator at 0.5 Hz?

It makes the signal a little more complex, which makes it easier to identify. Also easier to pick up with a simple receiver. You could have a second unit whose modulation is at, say, 700 Hz, and you'd be able to tell them apart. Better still, forget about the comparators -- put a 6- or 8-pin MCU in there and you can send arbitrarily complex IDs.

My technical analysis rather glossed over the real-world implications of these frequencies.  In simplest terms, if you had a 915 MHz receiver with an AM detector and a loudspeaker, you would hear a tone that turned on and off every other second.
